# Fix an element on ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I wanna do something like a [sticky menu](http://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/JLKbn), but I do not have any clue about this. My XML is something like this:

```
<com.example.customscrollview.scrollview
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- I need sticky this element bellow! -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="210.0dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="210.0dip">
            <!-- A lot of TextViews -->
            <TextView...>
            <TextView...>
            <TextView...>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</com.example.customscrollview.scrollview>
```

I tried do it programmatically:

```
private void setTouchListeners() {
    setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            boolean rt = false;
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                final View element = (View) findViewById(R.id.element);
                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        element.getHeight()
                );
                params.setMargins(0, (int) getScrollY(), 0, 0);
                params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                element.setLayoutParams(params);
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        childElement.requestLayout();
                    }
                });
            }
            return rt;
        }
    });
}
```

It works but isn't perfect. When the ScrollView begin fling, the movement isn't completed, because the `MotionEvent` only hook the touch events. So I overwrite the `onScrollChanged` to do the same function (with some changes). Good, now the element stays in the top, but it do not follow the scroll movement, it becomes "unstable" until the scroll stops (result of the fling and fast scroll velocity).

What is the better way to do it?

Comment: can you elaborate when you say _<!-- I need sticky this element bellow! -->_

Comment: @Elltz, I edited the question with a link to what I want to reach, here: http://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/JLKbn. The *<!-- I need sticky this element bellow! -->* is just to indicate who is the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get there most easily by changing the nesting. If you make the FrameLayout the root element, you can float the overlay on top of the ScrollView. The price that you pay is that it appears in the layout twice. If it's not too many views, that's probably worth paying.

You need programmatic control to change the `visibility` of the sticky navigation once the the scrolling navigation hits the top of the view. You don't need programmatic control to keep the sticky navigation in place.

```
<!-- FrameLayout simply positions all its children at the requested height, width, 
     gravity and margins. It doesn't try to avoid child views overlapping each
     other. The items are rendered in top-to-bottom XML order. -->
<FrameLayout layout_width="match_parent" 
             layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The scrollable main content. -->
    <ScrollView layout_width="match_parent" 
                layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout layout_width="match_parent"
                      layout_height="wrap_content"
                      orientation="vertical">

            <!-- The scrolling version of the navigation section -->
            <LinearLayout layout_width="match_parent" 
                          layout_height="wrap_content"
                          orientation="horizontal">
                <!-- menu items go here -->
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- content views go here. Note: if you're doing data binding to
                 populate this, consider RecyclerView instead of ScrollView. -->
            <TextView />
            <TextView />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- This is a copy of the navigation section. -->
    <LinearLayout layout_width="match_parent" 
                  layout_height="wrap_content"
                  layout_gravity="top" 
                  visibility="invisible"
                  orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- menu items go here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

(I've left out the `android:` prefixes for the example. You do need them.)

Comment: Perfect! I have a "header" in the root FrameLayout, when the invisible LinearLayout comes visible it overlaps the header. Is there a way to make the header overlap the LinearLayout, without send it to the bottom of XML?

Comment: If you give the header a fixed layout_height in `dp` instead of making it wrap_content, then you can put that same height as a layout_marginTop on the menu section.

Comment: Yes, I made that. Thank you so much :)

Comment: But, there has to be a code to prevent the object to be in a scrollView. Ordering some objects are not the fine solution.